# Scheme error: "Syntactic keyword may not be used as an expression: if"

Tags: scheme

I'm new to scheme and I'm trying to do a small very straight forward program.
But I keep getting this error message "Syntactic keyword may not be used as an expression: if".

Can anyone tell me if I'm missing something in my program or if I'm doing some sort of mistake?

Here is my program.

```
(define (foo lis k) 
(COND
  ((NULL? lis) '())
  (IF (< (CAR lis) k)
   (display (CAR lis))
  ELSE (display (CDR lis)))
))
(foo '(1 5 3 2 4) 3)
```

Thanks

-Gunnlaugur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but it seems like if is not needed there:

```
(define (foo lis k) 
  (cond
    ((null? lis) '())
    ((< (car lis) k)
      (display (car lis)))
    (else (display (cdr lis)))))
(foo '(1 5 3 2 4) 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

`cond` takes expressions in the form*

```
(condition  expr1 expr2  ... result)
```

Since you gave

```
(if (< (car lis) k) (display (car lis)) else (display (cdr lis)))
```

Scheme will try to see if `if` is true, and then run the next four expressions `(< (car lis) k)`, `(display (car lis))`, `else`, and `(display (cdr lis))`.  It runs into a couple problems, though.  `if` cannot be evaluated as true or false, since it is syntax.  Even if it could be, you would get a `misplaced aux keyword else` error.  And if that didn't happen, it would do *both* `(display (car lis))` and `(display (cdr lis))` (which is not what you want.

I'm guessing that you don't actually want to use `display`.  If you're running this interactively in a terminal, Scheme will evaluate the result of your function and print it for you.

---

`*` a slight simplification. Look in [TSPL4](http://www.scheme.com/tspl4/control.html#./control%3as13) for details.